# Shortcut key for send button in ChatGPT

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows, chatgpt

I usually use ChatGPT on a portrait monitor on a computer using [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows). Due to this, whenever I press the Enter key instead of triggering the send button, it just creates a new line.

My question is: How do I trigger the send button in fullscreen mode when using ChatGPT?

[image: Sample prompt in ChatGPT text box]

Comment: This is a site that reaches users from any place that has had access to the Internet for a long time. It might be helpful for you to mention the class of the keyboard layout you are using i.e. ANSI, ISO, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I can only answer based on my experience using Windows OS, which has a Windows button on its keyboard.

This is a problem for many people, and I hope that by sharing my findings, people will easily locate the solution.

Comment: You have replied to a comment that I posted about the question, not about the answer. When posting a self-answered question, write the question part as if you don't know the answer, and provide a minimal but complete context so others might reproduce the problem. Think that you might get other valuable answers besides the solution that you are sharing as answer.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut to trigger the send button, even when in fullscreen mode in ChatGPT, is simply by pressing **Windows + Alt + Enter**. In some browsers, **Windows + Enter** works.

Comment: What if the keyboard user does not include the Windows key? This is relevant because the question concerns a non-standard context, such as using an OEM's consumer (i.e., HP) desktop or laptop. It's just a rhetorical question; no answer/reply is expected.